# how can i embed wordpress backend in iframe

Tags: security, authorization, iframe

I have 2 websites http://www.aaa.com and http://www.bbb.com and need them to show the same.

Now I put an iframe in `index.html` and upload to aaa.com. It's ok for frontend but it's doesn't work for backend, where it shows a blank page.

Can anyone suggest me how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: hmmm this doesn't seem like the best approach to making this work, have you looked into multisite and domain mapping?

Answer (score 3):

By default WordPress sends an HTTP header to prevent iframe embedding on `/wp_admin/` and `/wp-login.php`:

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

That's a security feature. If you want to remove this header remove the filters:

```
remove_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header' );
remove_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header' );
```

But you should really use the multisite feature as Tom J Nowell suggested.

Comment: Thanks Tom and toscho :) the problem is I cannot control domain or anything in aaa.com, just ftp I can use for transfer files to site and it's not work properly on IIS server and sure admin cannot fix for me. so i decide to move to my hosting that I can control and it's Apache. everything works fine with iframe except backend :( did you guys have some suggestion ? thank you very much :D

Answer (score 3):

Tried to extend the version of @toscho

```
    //remove the restriction
    remove_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header' );
    remove_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header' );

    //for added security
    add_action( 'login_init', 'Access_Control_Allow_Origin' );
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'Access_Control_Allow_Origin' );


    function Access_Control_Allow_Origin(){
        $origin=get_http_origin();
        $allowed_origins=array(//add your domains or keeps empty
            "aaa.com",
            "bbb.com",
        );
        $allowed=false;
        if(count($allowed_origins)>0){
            foreach($allowed_origins as $allowed_origin){
                if (strstr($origin,$allowed_origin)){
                    $allowed=true;
                    break;
                }
            }       
        }else{
            $allowed=true;
        }
        if($allowed){
            return true;
        }else{
            send_origin_headers();
        }
    }
```