# Custom Login iframe doesn't work

Tags: login, wp-login-form, iframe

I have a custom login window that I am building. The client requires a modal window for the login, so I have to use HTTP (for performance) for the regular page, and HTTPS for the login window (in the iframe for security), because of this, I get the error:

> Refused to display 'https://www.wordpress.com/wp-login.php' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

I'm sure that this is a security feature so people can't iframe the `wp-login.php` page, but I want to remove it so this login will work properly. Is there anyway to remove the `'SAMEORIGIN' protection` for the `wp-login.php` page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some more research, I found this post: [how can i embed wordpress backend in iframe](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/how-can-i-embed-wordpress-backend-in-iframe). While the question it was asking didn't relate, the answer that toscho gave did. I'm reposting it here so it can be associated without click through:

> By default WordPress sends an HTTP header to prevent iframe embedding
> on /wp_admin/ and /wp-login.php:
>
> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN That's a security feature. If you want to
> remove this header remove the filters:
>
> `remove_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header' );`
> `remove_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header' );`