# Prevent other sites from showing my site via iframe

Tags: iframe

Right now, anyone can display my website with an `<iframe>` tag.

See example:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/" width="1000" height="1800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

How can I block a website from doing that?

I prefer use code than a plugin,
Thank you,
Shay.

Comment: I think you need this post:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843085/how-to-block-website-from-loading-in-iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843085/how-to-block-website-from-loading-in-iframe) Good luck

Answer (score 3):

WordPress has a built-in function to send the `X-Frame-Options` header: `send_frame_options_header()`. It is [used by default on the login and admin pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/49604/73).

If you want to enable it always, just add it for front end views:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'send_frame_options_header' );
```

But … it doesn't send [`Content-Security-Policy` headers](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet). If you want to have a [more complete solution](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Browser_Support) and disable any frame, even from the same site, you can use:

```
function no_frame_headers()
{
    header( "X-Frame-Options: DENY", true );
    header( "Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'", true );
}
```

And then register that callback:

```
add_action( 'login_init',        'no_frame_headers', 1000 );
add_action( 'admin_init',        'no_frame_headers', 1000 );
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'no_frame_headers', 1000 );
```

This has to go into a plugin, of course.

Comment: does this options will still let me show my website on my website via iframe?

Comment: @ShayS Then you have to use `frame-ancestors 'self'` and `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`.

Comment: thank you for responding! , what do you mean i have to use these? i need to add them to what you gave me?

Comment: @ShayS Yes, replace the parts in my code sample.